# Html.BeginForm does not post

Tags: post, html.beginform

I'm using AspNet Identity 2 without modification.  The Logon, Register, Change Password, etc. views fail to post when I deploy to WinHost.  Everything works OK when I deploy to my test server.  I can make the production app work if I remove all the HTML.BeginForm parameters.

This does not work:
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))

This works:
@using (Html.BeginForm())

I've tried various beginform overloads without success.  My app is MVC 5.2.7 with entity framework 4.6.1.  I'm using VS 2017 v 15.5.7

Comment: Further testing I found that this works: @using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))   Can someone help me understand why HTML.BeginForm works differently on my WinHost production app and my test server app?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  I had a URL Rewrite rule in IIS that caused a 301 rewrite if the URL had upper case characters.  The 301 redirect causes an HTTP POST to become a GET.  Disabling the rule fixed the problem. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect/99966#99966 says you can doe a 307 redirect.  I changed the rule to do a 307 but the POST was still redirected to a GET.  I left the rule disabled.